# Why can't I separate the creation of the function and the export when using Node/Expree and Pug?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In an app built using Node/Express, MongoDB/Mongoose and Pug, I have this controller function JS file named **indexController2.js** where I am exporting a funcioned named **index**.

I know that it will work perfectly if I write **exports.index...** However, I'd like to know why can't I separate the creation of the funciont form the export, just like shown in the below?

(Node returns an error of **Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]**)

```
function index(req, res) {
    Livro.countDocuments({}, function(err, results){
        if (err){
            res.render('livrariaIndex2', {title: 'Livraria JBM Home', count: 'Erro!!!!'});        
        } else {
            res.render('livrariaIndex2', {title: 'Livraria JBM Home', count: results});
        }
    })
}

exports.index;
```

Comment: I assume you should be using `exports.index = index;`.  Just executing `exports.index;` by itself does not do anything.

Comment: That was it @jfriend00. I was making some dumb confusion with the name of the export and the name of the function. That was a good example to assimilate the knowledge.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To successfully export your `index` function as the `index` export name, you must assign the `index` function to be an `index` property of the `exports` object.

So, you should be using:

```
exports.index = index;
```

Just executing this by itself:

```
exports.index;
```

does not do anything.  It doesn't assign anything to anything.

Comment: Thank you! I was making some confusion between assigning the name of the function and the name of the exported item